# Angular how to call Method from Sibling Component that is binded via <router-outlet>?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular-changedetection

I have a Project that uses HTTP Calls to fetch Data from API Endpoint and than display on Screen.
It's a simple ToDoList. So you can add Items to the list, see all Items in your List, delete items and so on.

The Project structure is this:

- Items-Component (Holds the entire App basically)

  - Item-list-component
  - Item-detail-component
  - Item-edit-component
  - item-add-component
- Item.service

The Items.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
  <app-item-list></app-item-list>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So we can see that the `item-list-component` and the other 3 components (binded via `router-outlet`) are **sibling components**, that's what I think.

So my **Problem** is now:
I want that whenever a new Item is created the items[] in the items.list component should refresh automatically. Now I must click a "Fetch Items" button to refresh the items[].

When I add a new Item, it fires a method from my item.service, it holds a fetchItems Method that just returns an Observable of the API Endpoint, like this:

Item-add component.ts:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-item-add',
  templateUrl: './item-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-add.component.css']
})
export class ItemAddComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onCreatePost(item: Item) {
    // Send Http request
    this.itemService.createAndStorePost(item.description, item.isComplete);
    //Here I want that the items[] in the items.list component refreshes when I add new Item
    this.onCancel();
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.router.navigate([''], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

}
```

And the item.service.ts:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ItemService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

    }

    fetchItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.http.get<Item[]>('https://localhost:44321/api/TodoItems');
    }

    fetchItem(id: number): Observable<Item> {
        return this.http.get<Item>('https://localhost:44321/api/TodoItems' + '/' + id);
    }

    createAndStorePost(description: string, isComplete: boolean) {
        var item = { description: description, isComplete: isComplete };
        this.http.post('https://localhost:44321/api/TodoItems', item)
            .subscribe(Response => {
            });
    }

    deleteItem(id: number): Observable<Item> {
        return this.http.delete<Item>('https://localhost:44321/api/TodoItems' + '/' + id);
    }

    updateItem(id:number, item: Item) {
        this.http.put<Item>('https://localhost:44321/api/TodoItems' + '/' + id, item).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Then the items-list component catches that Observable and subscribes to it and sets the Response from that subscription to and items[] in the component itself:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css']
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.onFetchItems();
  }

  onFetchItems() {
    this.itemService.fetchItems().subscribe(Response => {
      this.items = Response;
  });
  }
  onNewItem() {
    this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

}
```

What can I do to trigger that the items.list should fetch Items again?
I can't use @ViewChild because it is no Parent-Child relation.

Can I implement and instance of item.list anywhere in the project and just call the onFetchItems Method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use BehaviorSubject to share data between your different components.
Here is an example:

In your ItemService.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

 private _itemsSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);
 currentItems  = this._itemsSource.asObservable();
        
 constructor() { }

  updateItems(items: []): void {
    this._itemsSource.next(items)
  }


}
```

In your ItemsComponent, you update the new value in the service after you get all the items,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.onFetchItems();
  }

  onFetchItems() {
    this.itemService.fetchItems().subscribe(Response => {
      this.items = Response;
     this.updateItems(this.items)
  });
  }

  updateItems(newItems: []): void {
    this.itemService.updateItems(newItems)
  }

}
```

And in your ItemListComponent

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-item-list',
templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css']
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
items: Item[] = [];
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private itemService: ItemService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.itemService.currentItems.subscribe(items => this.items = items)
}

onNewItem() {
  this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Same behaviour as before when adding new Item the list doesn't refresh automatically.

Comment: Watch this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ac45jt?file=src/app/app.component.ts), isn't that the behavior you want?

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: But what is the _itemsSource Behaviour Subject and the.next method for?

Comment: The `BehaviorSubject` is a class which extends the `Subject ` class which extends the `Observable ` class, both therefore inherit the properties of `Observable `. As you can see, in the documentation,  "the `BehaviorSubject`  is variant of `Subject ` that requires an initial value and emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to," [rxjs-doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject).

Comment: Concerning the `next()` method, to keep it simple, you can see this method as the transmitter that will notify all your components that subscribe() to the `currentItems` `Obsevable`, for the new value.

Comment: Hi Madi Naf, thanks for your answer and example on stackblitz it helped.
I'm trying now to switch from using .subscribe() to async for accessing data from rest api in my project. I read that async is the bestter variant because you don't need to unsubscribe.

But my ngOnDestroy never gets called and therefore I can't unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy.
Should I open a new question for that?

Comment: You can search on google or directly on stackoverflow. And if you can't find a solution, you can close this question and ask another one with your current problem.